# How to explicitly pass an adjacency matrix when using scanpy.tl.louvain?

Tags: python, matrix, adjacency-matrix

Here is the description for [louvain in scanpy](https://scanpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/scanpy.tl.louvain.html).

I would like to pass a specific adj matrix, however, I tried the minimal example as follows and got the result of "Length of values (4) does not match length of index (6)". Is this mistake due to the misuse of the sparse matrix?

Code:

```
import scanpy as sc
import torch
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

nodes = [[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 10, 0, 0], [0, 11, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0]]
features = torch.tensor(nodes)
print(features.shape)

edgelist = [(0,1), (1,2), (2,3)]
G = nx.Graph(edgelist)
G_adj = nx.convert_matrix.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(G) # transform to scipy sparse matrix

adata = sc.AnnData(features.numpy())
sc.pp.neighbors(adata, n_neighbors=2, use_rep='X')
sc.tl.louvain(adata, resolution=0.01, adjacency=G_adj) # pass the adj here
y_pred = adata.obs['louvain'].astype(int).to_numpy()
n_clusters = len(np.unique(y_pred))
```

Could you point out what is wrong and provide an example of how to explicitly pass an adjacency matrix when using scanpy.tl.louvain? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`G` is a graph created with four nodes, and thus `G_adj` is a (4, 4) sparse matrix.
`adata` is a scanpy object with 6 observations, and four variables. the scanpy louvain algorithm clusters observations, and thus expects an adjacncy matrix of shape (6, 6).

Not sure what you were meaning to do:

If you truly have 6 nodes you should alter your code for the graph:

```
print(features.shape)

edgelist = [(0,1), (1,2), (2,3)]

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(range(6))
G.add_edges_from(edgelist)

G_adj = nx.convert_matrix.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(G) # transform to scipy sparse matrix

adata = sc.AnnData(features.numpy())
```

If you have 4 nodes, alter the adata creation line:

```
adata = sc.AnnData(features.numpy().T)
```